# bash read loop only reading first line of input variable

Tags: bash, delimiter

I have a read loop that is reading a variable but not behaving the way I expect.  I want to read every line of my variable and process each one.  Here is my loop:

```
while read -r line
do
   echo $line | sed 's/<\/td>/<\/td>$/g' | cut -d'$' -f2,3,4 >> file.txt
done <<< "$TABLE"
```

I expect it to process every line of the file but instead it just does the first one. If my the middle is simply echo $line >> file.txt it works as expected.  What's going on here?  How do I get the behavior I want?

Comment: Can you show output of `cat -vte <<< "$TABLE"`

Comment: The output is just `$`

Comment: So you original string `$TABLE` is empty?

Comment: My mistake the output is like this: `<tr><td></td><td></td>...</tr>^M<tr><td></td><td></td>...</tr>^M<tr><td></td>` and so on. All on one line.

Comment: Not sure I see the point of the whole `while` loop thing here, unless it's just whitespace removal. Why not just `sed '/<\/td>/<\/td>$/g' <<< "${TABLE}" | cut -d'$' -f2-4 > file.txt`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your lines are delimited by `\r` instead of `\n`.

Use this while loop to iterate the input with use of `read -d $'\r'`:

```
while read -rd $'\r' line; do
    echo "$line" | sed 's~</td>~</td>$~g' | cut -d'$' -f2,3,4 >> file.txt
done <<< "$TABLE"
```

Answer (score 0):

If `$TABLE` contains a multi-line string, I recommend

```
printf '%s\n' "$TABLE" |
while read -r line; do
   echo $line | sed 's/<\/td>/<\/td>$/g' | cut -d'$' -f2,3,4 >> file.txt
done
```

This is also more portable since the '<<<' operator for here-strings is not POSIX.

Comment: This will run `while` run in a subshell, which might not always be intended